# Visualizing Weights and Variance of Each Layer Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to visualize the weights and variance of each Layer of the following model in Keras, but the [code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualizing-the-vanishing-gradient-problem/) only shows the first layer weights and not all layers. The point here I would like to visualize the weights from all layers to see how the model update the layers during training for each eporch:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Lambda
import keras


def initialize_base_network():
    # passing input to layers
    input = Input(shape=(100,), name="base_input")
    x = Flatten(name="flatten_input")(input)
    x = Dropout(0.2, name="first_dropout")(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="first_base_dense")(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="second_base_dense")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1, name="second_dropout")(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="third_base_dense")(x)

    # return the model
    return Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)


def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    sum_square = K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sum_square, K.epsilon()))


def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    print(shape1[0], shape1, shape2)
    return (shape1[0], 1)


base_network = initialize_base_network()
# plot_model(base_network, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, to_file='base-model.png')
base_network.summary()

# create the left input and point to the base network
input_a = Input(shape=(100,), name="left_input")
vect_output_a = base_network(input_a)

# create the right input and point to the base network
input_b = Input(shape=(100,), name="right_input")
vect_output_b = base_network(input_b)

# measure the similarity of the two vector outputs
output = Lambda(euclidean_distance, name="output_layer", output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)(
    [vect_output_a, vect_output_b])

# specify the inputs and output of the model
model = Model([input_a, input_b], output)

model.summary()
# plot model graph
# plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, to_file='outer-model.png')
```

Output of summary:

[image]

Then compile and fit the model:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
 
class WeightCapture(Callback):
    "Capture the weights of each layer of the model"
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.weights = []
        self.epochs = []
 
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epochs.append(epoch) # remember the epoch axis
        weight = {}
        for layer in model.layers:
            if not layer.weights:
                continue
            name = layer.weights[0].name.split("/")[0]
            weight[name] = layer.weights[0].numpy()
        self.weights.append(weight)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.epochs.append(epoch) # remember the epoch axis
        weight = {}
        for layer in model.layers:
            if not layer.weights:
                continue
            name = layer.weights[0].name.split("/")[0]
            weight[name] = layer.weights[0].numpy()
        self.weights.append(weight)
 
#F1 SCORE
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    pred = y_pred.ravel() < 0.5 #all predictions less that 0.5 will return true (<0.5)
    return np.mean(pred == y_true)


from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()

def contrastive_loss_with_margin(margin):
    def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        square_pred = K.square(y_pred) #corresponds to Dw in our formula where y_true is either 0 or 1
        margin_square = K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0))
        return (y_true * square_pred + (1 - y_true) * margin_square)
    return contrastive_loss

from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss

class ContrastivLoss(Loss):
    def __init__(self, margin =1):
        super().__init__()
        self.margin = margin
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        square_pred = K.square(y_pred) #corresponds to Dw in our formula where y_true is either 0 or 1
        margin_square = K.square(K.maximum(self.margin - y_pred, 0))
        return K.mean(y_true * square_pred + (1 - y_true) * margin_square)


decay_steps = 1000
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=30)
capture_cb = WeightCapture(model)
capture_cb.on_epoch_end(-1)
callbacks_list = [capture_cb]

rms = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss=ContrastivLoss(margin=1), optimizer=rms, metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit([train_data[:,0], train_data[:,1]], labels_train,
                    validation_data=([test_data[:,0], test_data[:,1]], labels_test), epochs=10, 
                    batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=2)
```

**Problem**: Then plotting the weights of each layer only visualize the first layer weights mean and std:

```
def plotweight(capture_cb):
    "Plot the weights' mean and s.d. across epochs"
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 10))
    ax[0].set_title("Mean weight")
    for key in capture_cb.weights[0]:
        ax[0].plot(capture_cb.epochs, [w[key].mean() for w in capture_cb.weights], label=key)
    ax[0].legend()
    ax[1].set_title("S.D.")
    for key in capture_cb.weights[0]:
        ax[1].plot(capture_cb.epochs, [w[key].std() for w in capture_cb.weights], label=key)
    ax[1].legend()
    plt.show()
    
plotweight(capture_cb)
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You only access the first layer via the calls: "layer.weights[0]", try changing this 0 to access different layers.

Comment: @njp. Thanks. Same problem.